# Wordpress Website Not Loading in Chrome Desktop Version

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

** I figured out what was happening. We are using the WP Rocket Cache plugin on the site and I had set it to "minify javascript". Once I turned that option off, everything started working normally again. **

---

We have a Wordpress website (hosted on Bluehost) and we are not able to access it on the desktop version of Chrome (but only some computers).

This is the [link](https://www.stmarkboston.org/).

I have tried clearing my cache, cookies, etc. but nothing seems to work. We are able to access it on Safari and Firefox without a problem. I thought it might be a Bluehost problem but their support people were able to access it from their Chrome browser. It seems to be a problem on Macs.

Is there anyone who might know a solution?

Thank you,

Allie

Comment: I can load the website in chrome for windows. Nothing is wrong with your website. The problem is specific to your computer.

Comment: Can you show screenshot of screen? Is there any error?

Comment: It's most likely that the DNS cache on your computer has not been updated, so it's either corrupt or outdated. For chrome there are 2 dns caches, the one stored by windows and the one stored by chrome. For your specific chrome installation, go to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and click the `clear host cache` button to clear the chrome dns cache. Then use the following link and try `method 2`. https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1720415

Comment: You cannot clear the DNS cache by clearing the cache from the settings page of google chrome.

Comment: HOW is the website not loading? Do you see any error message? Is it a blank white screen? Post a screenshot.

Comment: Hi All,Thank you!

Here are a few screenshots:

1.) What the website looks like in Chrome (but it's not only on my computer...someone else sees the same error). Once you close the video window all you see is a spinning wheel:

https://pasteboard.co/JPZUoYU.png


2.) Here is what the website should look like:

https://pasteboard.co/JPZUGid.png

https://pasteboard.co/JPZUUFu.png